# How can i change existing Bokeh plot tick sizes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

How can i change the existing Bokeh plot ticks size, specifically package that was being used to plot already defined a plot layout of bokeh ? How can i overwrite those layout ? Below is the example code of the plot to reproduce the plot.

```py
# !pip install arlpy
import arlpy.uwapm as pm
import arlpy.plot as plt
env = pm.create_env2d()
pm.plot_env(env, width=900)
```

Here is the generated figure for which i want to redefined layout.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit tricky and but it is possible to get it done. But I have to mention that I don't like this solution.

To get a figure you have to enable the `hold` argument because otherwise it will be plotted immediately and return `None`. Then you can get the current figure using `arlpy.plot.gcf()` and set all parameters. To show the figure now you have to use the bokeh call `show` because the figure is a bokeh object now and in arlpy it is not available to set the `hold` to `False` again and show the figure. In fact the figure is now waiting for some data to add.

Here is an example.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
import arlpy.plot
arlpy.plot.figure(title='Demo 1', width=500)

arlpy.plot.plot([0,10], [0,10], hold=True)
p = arlpy.plot.gcf()
p.axis.major_tick_line_width = 3
show(p)
```

Unfortunately I found no solution where I use `import arlpy.uwapm as pm` because there is no return parameter in the `plot_env`function. So you can`t get the figure and make some changes.

I hope this helps. But I guess it is not satisfying.